# Android ListPopupWindow's method isShowing() does not work

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner

I've decided to create my own custom spinner by extending a `TextView` and composing a `ListPopupWindow`. I want to emulate the following functionality of the original `Spinner`: when the spinner is clicked the drop down list is shown, the second time the spinner is clicked the drop down list is dismissed. But I'm having some trouble, the `ListPopupWindow.isShowing()` seems to always return `false` (I've debugged it):

```
public class CustomSpinner extends TextView {
    ...
    private ListPopupWindow dropDownPopup;
    ...
    public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ...
        dropDownPopup = new ListPopupWindow(context, attrs);
        dropDownPopup.setAnchorView(this);
        dropDownPopup.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dropDownPopup.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                dropDownPopup.dismiss();
                ...
            }
        });     

        this.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                
                if (dropDownPopup.isShowing()) {
                    dropDownPopup.dismiss();
                } else {
                    dropDownPopup.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

So, each time I click on the spinner the drop down list is shown. It is dismissed when I click on one of the items in the list. The problem seems to be that `dropDownPopup.isShowing()` always returns `false`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By setting `dropDownPopup.setModal(true)`, everything works.

Comment: That's weird, with `setModal(true)` my onClick listener is not called at all when the popup is opened, but the popup disappears

Answer (score 0):

By adding `dropDownPopup.setInputMethodMode(ListPopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);`before`dropDownPopup.show();`, it works for me.